# Connection rds mysql to python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-rds

Here is my python code to connect to an rds mysql instance. I have ensured that connections are publicly accessible and have a security group named default_ that accepts all traffic from source 0.0.0.0/0. The code is giving the error Error: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'database-2.cgsvu7bg7jl5.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (timed out)")
I do not know what to do from here because I think it should be configured. Let me know if there are any steps I can take to debug.

```
import pymysql

host = 'database-2.extra_info.rds.amazonaws.com'
user = 'admin'
password = 'my_password'
database = 'test'

try:
    # Establish a connection to the database
    connection = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=database)

    # Create a cursor object to interact with the database
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Execute SQL queries or database operations here

        # Example: Execute a SELECT query
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM your_table_name")
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in results:
            print(row)

except Exception as e:
    print("Error: {}".format(e))
finally:
   # Close the database connection when done
   connection.close()
```

I expected to be able to connect to python and to mysql workbench but both seem not to be working

Comment: 1 - Please remove the real endpoint from the question. You should not publish the resolveable DNS address of your DB after saying it should be open to the world.
2 - Trying to `telnet` the address shows that it is not open on port 3306. If the you're sure that the security group is properly configured, make sure that the subnet is open to the world. This mean that it should be with an ACL that allows access and with an IGW in the routing table.

Comment: 3 - On the RDS itself, make sure it is set to `publicly-accessible`.